# How to convert my special dates to timezone via Google API

Tags: javascript

I want to change these dates via Google API to timezone. How can I do that. I am new on javascript. Thank you so much

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="starter-template">
        <h3>12.08.2020, 13:50</h3>
        <h3>15.08.2020, 14:50</h3>
        <h3>16.08.2020, 15:50</h3>
        <h3>18.08.2020, 16:50</h3>
        <h3>20.08.2020, 17:50</h3>
        <h3>21.08.2020, 18:50</h3>
        <h3>25.08.2020, 19:50</h3>
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"></select>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.10/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var timezone = moment.tz.names();
    for (var i = 0; i < timezone.length; i++) {
      $('select').append('<option value="12.05.2015' + timezone[i] + '">' + timezone[i] + '</option>');
    }
    $('select').selectpicker();
  </script>
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean to convert the dates inside `<div class="starter-template"></div>` to that specific timezone when a timezone is selected?

Comment: Yes. When someone want to change to their local timezone, All the dates in <div class="starter-template"></div> automatically must change.